# ExtJs 4.2.1 get data after model has been load

Tags: extjs4.2

I have Model

```
Ext.define('app.model.MyM', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {name: 'test'}
    ]

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'getdataHere'
    }

});
```

After I get my data loaded in a Model in a controller.

```
var m = this.getModel('MyM');
m.load(pId, {callback: function(){//do something}});
```

Later on I am trying to get loaded model data again but can not succeed,

```
Ext.ModelManager.getModel('MyM').getData() - an error - constructor.... does not have method getdata
this.getModel('MyM').getData() - the same error
```

Any ideas why? How do I get model data?

This is an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function constructor() {
            // Opera has some problems returning from a constructor when Dragonfly isn't running. The || null seems to
            // be sufficient to stop it misbehaving. Known to be required against 10.53, 11.51 and 11.61.
            return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments) || null;
        } has no method 'getData'
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a reference to the model in the callback:

```
Ext.define('MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        app.model.MyM.load(id, {
            scope: this,
            success: this.captureModel
        });

        this.control({
            button: {
                click: this.onFooClick
            }
        });
    },

    captureModel: function(rec) {
        this.rec = rec;
    },

    onFooClick: function() {
        console.log(this.rec);
    }
});
```

Comment: but I need to do something later, not in a callback. I know I can create global variable and use it later, but I did not want to do so.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use a global variable, surely you're doing it in some kind of context. Updated answer assuming you're loading from a controller. The same logic applies.

Comment: yes, I meant it. global variable in an app scope. While it works, do not really like this approach. Hoped I can load model and access it. Store does work this way. load it ones and access records.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. When you ask to load the model, it gives you the model instance. There's no "model cache".

Comment: You could write your own model cache.